# Python PriorityQueue. How to get() the data element instead of its priority number?

Tags: python-3.x, queue, priority-queue

I was wondering if there is any way to retrieve just the data element itself from a PriorityQueue instead of its priority number.

The example below prints number "11", as expected.
However, I need it to print the string "item A" only.

When I try:

a = q.get()[1]

I just get a TypeError saying "'int' object is not subscriptable".

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

q = PriorityQueue()

q.put(11, "item A")

a = q.get()

print(a)
```

Output:

```
11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
from queue import PriorityQueue
q = PriorityQueue()
b  = (11, "item A")
q.put(b)
a = q.get()
print(a[1])
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm slowly going mad because I feel like I have tried it before, but apparently not. This solves the problem :]

Comment: @DeadManProp don't mention it.  I'm happy that helped :)